# php zip infinite loop

Tags: php, zip

when  use php zip class to extract a zip file(in fact it's bad,but who knows?),

```
  $ unzip -t 1.zip 
    file #47:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  574665
    ...
    At least one error was detected in 1.zip.

    <?php
    function unzip($apkpath, $dirname) { //
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $res = $zip->open($apkpath);
        if ($res === TRUE) {
            $zip->extractTo($dirname);
            $zip->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    unzip('com.nd.sms.zip', '2');  // It's ok
    //unzip('1.zip', '2');            //this line go into infinite loop and very heigh cpu
    unzip('com.nd.sms.zip', '2');
    ?>
```

**Anyone know how to safely use ZipArchive,or other extension replace,or some way to check zip file is valid?**
in addition,I use php5.3.14+ubuntu. 

And I knows there,
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53230
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57905

Comment: Keep your system libraries updated for security reasons. Then you are fine. Contact your system administrator about the options you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
function zipValid($path) {
  $zip = zip_open($path);
  if (is_resource($zip)) {
    // valid zip
    zip_close($zip);
    return true;
  }
else 
return false;
```

**Other ways**:

1. You can check the zip file's length against that in its header, but that might not help detect a corrupt file. You will need to comput CRC for the zip and compare it to the original CRC to know for sure.
   The original CRC might not be available to you though.
2. If it is a local system you are doing this in, you could use the PHP [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function and pass arguments to directly use the unzip executable.

Comment: yeah, may be i must use exec function to check zip file before use zip    function/class.

Comment: The PHP method of checking works. The exec method is just suggested as an alternative. You can use that if the PHP zipValid approach fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
function unzip($apkpath, $dirname) {
    exec('unzip -t '.$apkpath.'>/dev/null 2>&1', $out, $return);
    if($return === 0)
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $res = $zip->open($apkpath);
        if ($res === TRUE) {
            $zip->extractTo($dirname);
            $zip->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Well,It works.But I do not think its a good solution to extract a zip, no matter file data validation.